# Identify Flutter App has been open by clicking on the App Icon

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Is there any way in *flutter* to identify if the App has been opened by clicking on the App Icon *or* by some other options like Push Notification or deep linking.

If there is a way to identify the App has been opened by clicking on the App Icon I can deal with the other cases.

I tried to play with `WidgetsBindingObserver` but all it could give me is the state of the application *or* it is possible that somehow I'm missing some obvious part!!

N.B -- I'm not using Firebase Messaging.

Comment: Can you app also be opened by notification or other means?

Comment: Sorry for not to be clear. For e.g - take 2 cases. 1. By clicking on the App Icon 2. By clicking on the push notification. How can I distinguish these two different actions?

Comment: OK, how are you opening the app using notification natively or using any flutter package?

Comment: I've written my own plugin to work with Pubnub PN. And Currently opening the app from Native when it comes to PN. But somehow I want to take that all business here. My idea is almost the same as FCM plugin but just using Pubnub's SDK.

Comment: I know I can handle that on Native side but if I can do it on Flutter side, that would be a benefit for me.

Comment: I am not sure if you would be able to do that in dart, but it is easily achievable natively.

Comment: Okiee. Thanks a lot, @CopsOnRoad. :)

Answer (score 7):

For Flutter push notifications through firebase, you can use the following callbacks to check if the app is opened through push notification

**onMessage**: if the app is currently running (foreground) it will return you a stream of remote messages

**onMessageOpenedApp**: When the app is in background mode and the user has opened it using push notification, it will return you again stream of remote messages
Note: it will not work if the app is terminated or not running for the following method is used

**FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()**: it will work if the app is opened through push notification when it was in termination state, return a remote message not a stream of messages

Hope this will be helpful

Thanks